# Quickest way to clone element and autioincrement id (jquery)

Tags: jquery

A simple task of cloning an element and autoincrement its id.

can it be done in 1 line?

Comment: IDs beginning with a number technically aren't legal.

Comment: @cletus - It seems they allow it in HTML 5 (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#the-id-attribute). The value must contain at least one character and that it can’t contain any spaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**jQuery**

```
var NewElement=$("#test1").clone();  // Clone the element
var IDNr=NewElement.attr("id").match(/\d+$/);  // Grab the ID number

NewElement.attr("id",NewElement.attr("id").replace(IDNr,parseInt(IDNr)+1));  // Increment the ID
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1">Test</div>
```

[Code in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/hAKye/)