# Clone <div> and change id

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I using javascript make clone of some `<div>` and set his id different from original. Jquery  also will be nice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone element with new id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993373/how-to-clone-element-with-new-id) and [Quickest way to clone element and autioincrement id (jquery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274156/quickest-way-to-clone-element-and-autioincrement-id-jquery) and [many more](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+clone+element+change+id) -- please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: Really sorry. Guess I dont formed question in the search field correctly.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

```
var div = document.getElementById('div_id'),
    clone = div.cloneNode(true); // true means clone all childNodes and all event handlers
clone.id = "some_id";
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

Comment: Pure javascript? Thank you.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408394/how-to-copy-a-dom-node-with-event-listeners the event handlers are not copied (they are if the listener was added inline in html).

Comment: With (true), its doing a deep copy, yet the id's of the cloned children are not being updated in this answer.

Answer (score 8):

Use it:

**JQuery**

```
var clonedDiv = $('#yourDivId').clone();
clonedDiv.attr("id", "newId");
$('#yourDivId').after(cloneDiv);
```

Comment: `$('#yourDivId').after(cloneDiv);` might be a better solution there.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem. I've solved that by setting a counter and appending it to the ID. Hope it helps you too:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var counter = 1; //Set counter

function clone(sender, eventArgs) {
     var $row = $('#yourID');

     var $clone = $row.clone(); //Making the clone                      
     counter++; // +1 counter

     //Change the id of the cloned elements, append the counter onto the ID 
     $clone.find('[id]').each(function () { this.id += counter });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function contactCloseMe(element) {
  $(element).closest(".row").remove();
}

function contactAddMoreField(setion_id) {
  var container = $('#' + setion_id);
  var item = container.find('.contact-default').clone();
  item.find('input').val('');
  item.removeClass('contact-default').removeClass('d-none');
  item.appendTo(container).show();
  var newButton =
    '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm btn-icon" style="margin-top:-13px" onclick="contactCloseMe(this);"> <i class="bi bi-x"></i> </button>';
  item.find('div:last').show().append(newButton);
  $(this).closest('div').after(item);
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div id="email_contact">
    <div class="row contact-default">
      <div class="col-sm-11">
        <div class="row">
          <label for="last_name">Email*</label>
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email" name="email" class="form-control flat" onchange="store_data(this)" value="{{ $provider->email }}" required>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-1 text-center mt-5"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm flat float-end mt-3" onclick="contactAddMoreField('email_contact')">+ Add More Email</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to change the ID as required.

Comment: To help you better, please provide more details about your specific issue. Code snippets, error messages, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise questions get quicker and more accurate responses. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your question with specifics, and I'll assist you further. For more information on how to write good answers check out: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score -2):

jQuery have method clone()

```
var original = $("#original");
var newClone = original.clone();
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?