# How to copy a DOM node with event listeners?

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I tried

```
node.cloneNode(true); // deep copy
```

It doesn't seem to copy the event listeners that I added using `node.addEventListener("click", someFunc);`.

We use the Dojo library.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

`cloneNode()` does not copy event listeners. In fact, there's no way of getting hold of event listeners via the DOM once they've been attached, so your options are:

- Add all the event listeners manually to your cloned node
- Refactor your code to use event delegation so that all event handlers are attached to a node that contains both the original and the clone
- Use a wrapper function around `Node.addEventListener()` to keep track of listeners added to each node. This is how jQuery's [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method is able to copy a node with its event listeners, for example.

Comment: Do you perhaps have an example of code how to add event listeners to the cloned code?

Comment: @RoelofCoertze - you would have to know which events listeners were added in the first place and also have access in the code's place where you've done the cloning, to assign the callbacks again, since accessing the callbacks might be tricky depending where the cloning took place in the code, so an example will be useless since there are too many scenarios.

Comment: Currently faced with this issue. It seems that cloneNode behaves quite tricky when we are talking about event listeners copy: `It does not copy event listeners added using addEventListener() or those assigned to element properties (e.g., node.onclick = fn).`

Comment: @jeromej it is not always a bad habit: there are use cases when separating JS from HTML is undesirable, i.e. `<b onclick="this.nextElementSibling.innerHTML+='X'"><div></div>` loaded by AJAX means race hazard (and accidental complexity) if you separate it. Separating is good for extending reasons, but some code can be sealed by design. Both content attributes and IDL attributes exist for a reason.

Answer (score 21):

This does not answer the question exactly, but if the use case allows for *moving* the element rather than *copying* it, you can use [removeChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) together with [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) which will preserve the event listeners. For example:

```
function relocateElementBySelector(elementSelector, destSelector) {
  let element = document.querySelector(elementSelector);
  let elementParent = element.parentElement;
  let destElement = document.querySelector(destSelector);
  elementParent.removeChild(element);
  destElement.appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: P.S. It looks like the `removeChild()` step is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

**Event Delegation example.**

After reading Tim Down's answer, I found delegated events are very easy to implement, solving a similar problem I had. I thought I would add a concrete example, although it's in JQuery not Dojo.

I am re-skining an application in Semantic UI, which requires a small piece of JS to make the message close buttons work. However the messages are cloned from an HTML template tag using `document.importNode` in a library. This meant even if I did attach the event handlers to the template in the new HTML, they are lost during the cloning.

I cannot do Tim's option 1, to simply re-attach them during cloning as the messaging library is front-end framework agnostic. (Interestingly my previous front-end was in Zurb Foundation which uses a "data-closable" attribute, the functionality of which does survive the cloning process).

The [normal event handling suggested was like this](https://semantic-ui.com/collections/message.html#dismissable-block):

```
$('.message .close').on('click', function() {
    $(this)
    .closest('.message')
    .transition('fade');
});
```

The problem being ".message" at app-load only matches the single template, not the actual messages which arrive later over web-sockets.

Making this delegated, meant attaching the event to the container into which the messages get cloned `<div id="user-messages">`

So it becomes:

```
$('#user-messages').on('click', '.message .close', function() {
    $(this)
    .closest('.message')
    .transition('fade');
});
```

This worked immediately, saving any complex work like the third option of wrapping the event subs.

The [Dojo equivalent](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/on.html#event-delegation) looks pretty similar in concept.

Answer (score 2):

Only inline attributes would work here which are heavily, heavily discouraged because of how misused they are. That said, you can have elements bind to the same event listener.

The proper way with Web Components (and shadow root) would look like and what we would want to replicate:

```js
onButtonClick(event) {
  console.log('onButtonClick', { event, this: this });
}

/* Or constructor */
connectedCallback() {
  this.shadowRoot.getElementById('button')
    .addEventListener(this.onButtonClick);
}
```

It's efficient because you don't create function per element like you would with `.addEventListener(() => this.onButtonClick)`. 1000 buttons would attach to the same function instead of creating a new function per button.

To convert that to inline would look like this:

```html
<button onclick="this.getRootNode().host.onButtonClick.call(this, event)">
```

Is it ugly? Yes. But does it work? Also, yes. In this case there's no need for JS to have find the element and instruct the browser to create an event handler. The inline `onclick` does that for you. I will note that are creating a new function for each and every element, instead of them all sharing one.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [@JeromeJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408394/how-to-copy-a-dom-node-with-event-listeners#comment76730835_15411683) was describing in a comment.  Create the initial element using this HTML code.

`<DIV ONCLICK="doSomething(this)">touch me</DIV>`

When you clone this element the result will have the same handler, and "this" will point to the cloned element.

It would be great if the ONCLICK handler could easily be added in JavaScript.  This approach means that you have to write some of your code in HTML.

Comment: This is also called content attribute, which is independent to [IDL attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IDL).

Answer (score 1):

Cloning a node copies all of its attributes and their values, including intrinsic (inline) listeners. It does not copy event listeners added using addEventListener() or those assigned to element properties (e.g., node.onclick = someFunction). Additionally, for a  element, the painted image is not copied.

source: MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const _originAddEventListener = HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener;
const _originRemoveEventListener = HTMLElement.prototype.removeEventListener;
const _originCloneNode = HTMLElement.prototype.cloneNode;
const _eventListeners = [];

const getEventIndex = (target, targetArgs) => _eventListeners.findIndex(([elem, args]) => {
    if(elem !== target) {
        return false;
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        if(targetArgs[i] !== args[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
});

const getEvents = (target) => _eventListeners.filter(([elem]) => {
    return elem === target;
});

const cloneEvents = (source, element, deep) => {
    for (const [_, args] of getEvents(source)) {
        _originAddEventListener.apply(element, args);
    }

    if(deep) {
        for(const i of source.childNodes.keys()) {
            const sourceNode = source.childNodes.item(i);
            if(sourceNode instanceof HTMLElement) {
                const targetNode = element.childNodes.item(i);
                cloneEvents(sourceNode, targetNode, deep);
            }
        }
    }
};

HTMLElement.prototype.addEventListener = function() {
    _eventListeners.push([this, arguments]);
    return _originAddEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
};

HTMLElement.prototype.removeEventListener = function() {

    const eventIndex = getEventIndex(this, arguments);

    if(eventIndex !== -1) {
        _eventListeners.splice(eventIndex, 1);
    }

    return _originRemoveEventListener.apply(this, arguments);
};

HTMLElement.prototype.cloneNode = function(deep) {
    const clonedNode = _originCloneNode.apply(this, arguments);
    if(clonedNode instanceof HTMLElement){
        cloneEvents(this, clonedNode, deep);
    }
    return clonedNode;
};
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Though it's impossible to clone a node altogether with its event listeners, it's possible to pass the event back to the origin element, to get similar effects.

Here's an implementation of this idea: https://gist.github.com/MicroCBer/a412a6c27a6dc0e49c091ce64e96ae6b

You can test it through this script:

```js
// run in any Stackoverflow question pages with answers.

// This would create a perfect delegate dom of answers element, all the buttons should be interactable.
// sadly, the keyboard input is not working

const win = window.open('about:blank', undefined, 'popup');

for(const style of document.querySelectorAll('style, link')) 
    win.document.head.appendChild(style.cloneNode(true));

win.document.body.appendChild(createElementDelegate(document.querySelector("#answers"), {cloneParent:true, syncProps: true}))
```

```html
<script src="https://gist.githubusercontent.com/MicroCBer/a412a6c27a6dc0e49c091ce64e96ae6b/raw/9553ffa4af0d79980212d7fdf9c884cdbf3f3d16/cloneEx.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I know I'm late to the party but this a solution that worked for me:

```
const originalButtons = original.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('button');
const cloneButtons = clone.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('button');
originalButtons.forEach((originalButton: HTMLElement, index: number) => {
  cloneButtons[index].after(originalButton);
  cloneButtons[index].remove();
});
```

Comment: how does this answer the question? what is `original` and `clone` objects? and more important, the events from the `original` are not copied into the `clone` element in any way