# Javascript - Find and duplicate dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

How I can duplicate the following content in JavaScript? 
I want to have two dropdown's in the same page.

```
<fieldset id="product-options-wrapper" class="product-options">
  <dl class="last">
    <dt>
    <label class="required">
    <em>*</em>
    Pack Size/Price
    </label>
    </dt>
    <dd class="last">
      <div class="input-box">
        <select id="attribute148" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" name="super_attribute[148]" onchange="return changeSku(148, this);">
          <option value="">Choose an Option...</option>
          <option value="76">10g: €9.60</option>
          <option value="61">25g: €17.40</option>
          <option value="78">100g: €43.80</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </dd>
  </dl>
```

Thank you

Comment: use https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: why would you want to have 2 select with same options in one page?use `.find()` with `.clone()`

Comment: Also, remove the id and use only class or set a different id for the cloned element.

Comment: Note: the `<select>` has an id `attribute148` and anything with an id should not be duplicated without at least changing the id to something new and unique.

Comment: Please see ► [**how-to-copy-a-dom-node-with-event-listeners**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408394/how-to-copy-a-dom-node-with-event-listeners) and if using jQuery ► [**jQuery Clone**](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) Try those and if you have issues, feel free to post your code and can help you with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $select = document.querySelector('select#attribute148');
$select.id = "newId";
document.querySelector('yourNewDivId').appendChild($select);
```

First you get the actual select to JS. Then you update the id and at last you add it to the div, where you wanna have it.

**EDIT for Comment**

You could build a template:

```
function createSelect(id, options){
    var $select = document.createElement('select');
    $select.id = id;
    for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
        var $option = document.createElement('option');
        $option.value = options[i].value;
        $option.innerHTML = options[i].name;
        $select.appendChild($option);
    }
    return $select;
}
var select = createSelect(48, [{value: 76, name: "10g: €9.60}, ...]);
document.querySelector('target').appendChild(select);
```

Comment: the ID is not static, so we can't this

Comment: so this code is not static that attributeID and the select options will not be the same, what you see is for one product I have many products.

Comment: With the template function you can add a id, which ever you wanna use. Its completly individuell.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: I'll do a jsfiddle for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `cloneNode` method for this.

```
var el = document.getElementById('product-options-wrapper');
var dupEl = el.cloneNode();

dupEl.id = "some-new-id";
document.getElementById('some-container').appendChild(dupEl);
```

EDIT: Updated with full code example

Answer (score 0):

Test this out!

```
document.getElementById("product-options-wrapper").onclick = function(){ // when the fieldset is clicked
    var clone = this.cloneNode(true); 
    this.appendChild(clone); // clone it and append to the last fieldset
}
```

When a user clicks on the specified `fieldset`, it will clone it, and append the new clone, to the previous.

You can change what the new clone is appended to by changing `this.appendChild(clone)` to `document.getElementById("yourid").appendChild(clone)`

Hope this helps! :-)

Comment: Thank you but what I need is to duplicate that dropdown, in fact to duplicate as a list, I want to get the dropdown options and then to clone this and list in another div. so I don't need any click event