# Multiple unwanted clicks with showing/hiding DIV elements Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, function, click

I have written a function which hides or shows the content of a div when you click on the applicable button. However, when I do so, you have to click the button a couple of times before it shows the content. After that only one click is needed until you click on a unrelated button then the same thing happens. Here is the function: Does anybody have a solution please?

```
function openBtn(){
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.display === "block") {
              panel.style.display = "none";
          } else {
              panel.style.display = "block";
          }
      };
  }
}
```

UPDATE
Here is the full code for the website as requested:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sample_reception_page.css">
<style>
.accordion {
    background-color: #eee;
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
.active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: #ccc; 
}
.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.close {
  float: right;
  padding: 12px 16px 12px 16px;
}
.close:hover {
  background-color: #f44336;
  color: white;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Example</h2>
<button onclick="newSample()">ADD</button>

<div id="samplesinfo">
    <div class="test">
        <button onclick="delbtn()" class="delbtn" id="delbtn" style="float: right;">Delete</button>
        <button onclick="openBtn()" id="sample" class="accordion" style="float: left;">Button</button>
        <div id="usrInput" class="panel">
          <input type="text" name="test">
        </div>        
    </div>  
</div>
<div id="paste">    
</div>


<script>


function openBtn(){
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.display === "block") {
              panel.style.display = "none";
          } else {
              panel.style.display = "block";
          }
      };
  }
} 

  function newSample() {        
    var variable = document.getElementById("samplesinfo");
    var copy = variable.cloneNode(true);
    var paste = document.getElementById("paste");
    paste.appendChild(copy)
  }

function delbtn() {
  var delbtn = document.getElementsByClassName("delbtn");
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < delbtn.length; i++) {
    delbtn[i].onclick = function() {
        var div = this.parentElement;
        div.remove(div);        
    }
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not clear what is your query. Can elaborate it ? `After that only one click is needed until you click on a unrelated button then the same thing happens`

Comment: And you should probably show the related markup as well, because its structure is not really clear from the code above.

Comment: For example, I would click on the button that should hide or show the content of the div, but I have to click multiple times until it does so. Once it hides or shows the content I can click it once to hide or show. But if I click another button with a different function and then back to the first button I have to click again multiple times before it works again.

Comment: See edit above, the first function is the code causing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're applying muliple onclicks to the button with `class="accordion"`.

Remove inline onclick from this button:

```
<button id="sample" class="accordion" style="float: left;">Button</button>
```

and call `openBtn` after defining it.

```
function openBtn() {
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (panel.style.display === "block") {
              panel.style.display = "none";
          } else {
              panel.style.display = "block";
          }
      };
  }
}
openBtn()
```

Probably change the name of `openBtn` function also to reflect what it is actually doing which is adding onclick event listener to all the buttons with class `accordion`.

Comment: It works, but once you use the "add" button, the appended buttons do not work.

Comment: Here's the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408394/how-to-copy-a-dom-node-with-event-listeners

in short, `cloneNode` doesn't copy event listeners. You've to apply them again.

Comment: How would I reapply an eventlistener?