# Making an onClick="" attribute in vue while referring to the component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-events

I need to attach an `onClick=""` event to a Vue component. I am aware that I can use `@click=""`, but since this `div` is later going to be cloned (I am using a slider library that clones the `div`s). I cannot use `@click=""`, since the original event handler will not be cloned ([apparently this is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408394/how-to-copy-a-dom-node-with-event-listeners)).

How can I use a vanilla `onClick` event handler inside a component, while also referring to the component's method? Usually I'd write:

```html
<a href="#" @click="nextSlide()">
```

But I cannot use:

```html
<a href="#" onClick="this.nextSlide()">
```

Since "nextSlide" will then not be defined.

Comment: How are you cloning the element?  If vue clones the element, then vue could also establish the `@click` on the cloned element

Comment: could you share some code so we can see your cloning implementation?

Comment: The link you included shows that all event handlers (including native ones) would not be cloned, so access to the component method from the native handler wouldn't help.

Comment: I ended up assigning the click even register on the mounted method. I am not cloning the contents, but the slider library I am using is: https://pawelgrzybek.github.io/siema/

Comment: @tony19 and by the way, yes, because onClick is an HTML attribute and that would be cloned.