# appending div (with dropdown menu) that contains the tags <form:XXX>

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am using `form:options` in my JSP in order to populate a dropdown menu (options):

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<form:select class="form-control input-sm" path="openUrlKeySelected" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="abc">
    <form:option value="0">--Choose--</form:option>
    <form:options items="${keysModel.keys}"/>
</form:select>
```

When clicking some button (+) I need to add additional dropdown menu with the same values.

The problem is when trying to add the new div (in jQuery) it's fail when using the tag "form:*" in the new html STRING.

```
                var html =  '<div class="col-md-4">'+
                        '<form:select class="form-control input-sm" path="openUrlKeySelected" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="abc">'+
                        '<form:option value="0">--Choose--</form:option>'+
                        '<form:options items="${keysModel.keys}"/>'+
                        '</form:select>'+
                        '</div>';
```

If I'm not allowed to use `"<form:options>, <form:select>, <form:options>,...` when trying to append html, then is there other proper way?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't use `form:*` tags in your javascript because by then, no one will be able to process it.

What you can do is to [`clone()`](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the rendered dropdown (ex. get by ID, so you need an ID for your dropdown) and `append()` to so wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks! I found additional example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985156/clone-div-and-change-id