# Show div when click on a different div, and show a different div when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have made a way so the user can add another text field to the form by pressing on a 'add_another' div, this uses basic JS so when the user presses on the div 'add_another' the div 'author_2' is toggled.

I would like to make it so that when the user presses on the 'add_another' div for a second time it shows 'author_3' div, and when they press 'add_another' again, it then shows 'author_4'. I have put all the CSS and HTML divs in place to support this, I am just trying to adapt my code so it shows one div after another, rather then toggling a single div.

Here is my JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.add_another').on('click', function(){
            $('.author_2').toggle();
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

I have tried altering this code, however with no luck.

I haven't added my HTML as it is just 4 divs, 'author_1' 'author_2' ... 3...4

Thankyou for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions to Your problem. 
**First one - use static code**
It means the max author count is 4 and if user gets to 4, this is it.
If so - You need to store the number of authors already shown.

```
        var authors_shown = 1;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.add_another').on('click', function(){
                authors_shown++;
                if (!$('.author_'+authors_shown).is(":visible")) {
                   $('.author_'+authors_shown).toggle();
                }
            });
        });
```

But there is also a **second** - more **dynamic option**. 
What if user wants to input 10 or 20 authors? You don't want to pre render all that html code and hide it. You should [clone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985156/clone-div-and-change-id) the div and change its id or if the (HTML) code (for another author) is not too long, you can render it within JS code.

```
    var div = document.getElementById('div_id'),
    clone = div.cloneNode(true); // true means clone all childNodes and all event handlers
    clone.id = "some_id";
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

If it's a form, then change names of input fields to array as `author_firstname[]` 
Also You can store number of added authors in another hidden field (so you know how long to loop the form fields on the server side. 
The second option is a bit more complex and longer, but way more dynamic.

Comment: Maybe you have a typo. Check my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m3sd3v7v/1) as an example

Answer (score 0):

You should make another div when clicked on add_another:
something like this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.add_another').on('click', function(){
            $('<div><input type="text" name="name[]" /></div>').appendTo('.your_container');
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

as you see, input's name has [] which means you should treat with the inputs as an array.

let me know if you got any further questions

good luck.